# How to write a multi-line property in the auto-props section of the subversion config file?

Tags: svn, automatic-properties, svnignore, svn-config

What is the correct syntax?

```
[auto-props]
*.* = svn:ignore=bin
obj
```

or

```
[auto-props]
*.* = svn:ignore=bin;obj
```

or none? Is it possible to write multi-line properties in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case I found out that the right way of doing what I was trying to achieve was to include the following lines in the config file:

```
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
global-ignores = bin obj
```

So I think the same syntax (space as line separator) would apply for `auto-props`